# weird path URL to make $_POST working properly in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

So, for some reason my $_POST not working at all when used form open

`<?=form_open(base_url()."/Product/add/"); ?>`

But when changed the code like this:

`<?=form_open(base_url()."/Product/add/_"); ?>`

For some reason the $_POST is working fine.
Any idea why this is happening?

here's the controller

```
namespace App\Controllers;

class Product extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {        
        helper('form');
        return view('Product');
    }

    public function add(){     
        helper('form');
        var_dump($_POST);
    }
}
```

This is the routes I never edit anything.

```
<?php

namespace Config;

// Create a new instance of our RouteCollection class.
$routes = Services::routes();

if (file_exists(SYSTEMPATH . 'Config/Routes.php')) {
    require SYSTEMPATH . 'Config/Routes.php';
}

$routes->setDefaultNamespace('App\Controllers');
$routes->setDefaultController('Home');
$routes->setDefaultMethod('index');
$routes->setTranslateURIDashes(false);
$routes->set404Override();
$routes->setAutoRoute(true);

$routes->get('/', 'Home::index');


if (file_exists(APPPATH . 'Config/' . ENVIRONMENT . '/Routes.php')) {
    require APPPATH . 'Config/' . ENVIRONMENT . '/Routes.php';
}
```

Comment: show the controller function code for better understanding

Comment: Show us your routes under `app\Config\Routes.php`, please.

Comment: Added, but the routes are default.

Comment: Check the page source, is the rendered HTML `action` really `/Product/add/_`? Check your browser devtools network tab when you submit the form, is it really POSTing there, and is the server really responding 200/OK?  What do your CI, PHP, web server logs show, anything interesting?  And what does "*$_POST not working at all*" mean, exactly?

Comment: basically, it won't get any post data, the post is empty array (array 0 {}), but for some reason if I put something like /Product/add/<writeanythinghere>, the post array work fine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.